# "prefer-ip-address" of Eureka client not work in docker container

Tags: docker, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I have a Spring Cloud Eureka client instance running inside docker, and I would like the client to register itself the host's IP address rather than the container's hostname to the Eureka server, so I set `eureka.instance.ip-address: xx.xx.xx.xx` and `eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address: true` to the client's `application.yml`, but that does not work, it still registers the container's hostname to the server, any help is appreciated!

```
spring:
  application:
    name: uaa-service
server:
  port: 8799

eureka:
  service-url:
    defaultZone: https://XX.YY.ZZ/eureka/
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
    ip-address: xx.xx.xx.xx
```

[image: screenshot]
My Spring Boot version is `2.0.0.RELEASE` and Spring Cloud being `Finchley.M9`.

Comment: what is in `<eurekaserver>/apps`? what is displayed there isn't what is sent to clients.

Answer (score 1):

Give this in your spring service

```
spring:
  application:
    name: uaa-service
  cloud:
    inetutils:
      ignored-interfaces:
        - eth0
        - eth1
        - eth2
        - eth3
        - lo
```

Taken from [this](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1646#issuecomment-357213927)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the same version of spring-boot and have a similar problem

But I think you are confusing IP address with the instance ID.

See this link: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1646#issuecomment-275121055

When you hover the mouse over the link or click on it, does it show the right IP-Address?

Anyway, I have two applications, one using spring-boot 1.5 where this property works.

With the 2.0 version the application always use the machine IP, instead what I informed in the `eureka.instance.ip-address`.

---

Edit > I reported a bug here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/2878